# Combining result of independent select queries into one table

Tags: mysql

I am learning how to write queries in `MySQL`, I have a table that holds transactions and wanted to get total `1. revenues sold through the full life span`, `2. Revenues in a day`, `3. Revenues in a week` and `4. Revenues in a month`. All of which return **tables having same columns**.

So I have two tables the transaction table that holds all my transactions and price table that holds prices of all items, when making a purchase of an item I get the itemid from the price table so for me to fetch a price of a transaction i need to join the two, here are my table structures:

price table

```
         |priceid | itemName | price |
         -----------------------------
         |1      |Bread     | 20    |
```

transaction table

```
        |transactionid |pricefk |  transactiondate |
        --------------------------------------------
        |112           |1       |2018-03-22 19:15:05|
```

I know how to get the total revenue, revenue in a day, week and month using 3 queries but wanted a way to get all the 3 values in one query

What I know is

```
SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk
```

Gets all lifetime revenues

```
SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  where t.transactiondate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Gets revenues in a day

```
SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  where YEARWEEK(t.transactiondate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

Gets revenues in a week

```
SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  WHERE MONTH(t.transactiondate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(t.transactiondate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Gets revenues in a month

> How can I combine all these queries in one query?

Answer (score 0):

## Quickfix

You can wrap them in a select as shown below:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(p.price) FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk) 
as lifetimeRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(p.price) FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  where t.transactiondate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
as dayRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(p.price) FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  where YEARWEEK(t.transactiondate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) 
as weekRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(p.price) FROM transaction_table t JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  WHERE MONTH(t.transactiondate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(t.transactiondate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) 
as monthRevenue
```

Working fiddle here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70ef6/5

## Making it simpler

You are not making use of any foreign keys, they will help in keeping data integrity and the queries become much simpler by using that.

You would add something like this in your create table statement for `transaction_table`.

```
foreign key (pricefk) references price_tb(priceid)
```

After which in all the join statements on tables will instead contain just the table names:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(price) FROM transaction_table,price_tb)
as lifetimeRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(price) FROM transaction_table,price_tb where transactiondate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
as dayRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(price) FROM transaction_table,price_tb where YEARWEEK(transactiondate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) 
as weekRevenue,
(SELECT  SUM(price) FROM transaction_table,price_tb WHERE MONTH(transactiondate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(transactiondate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) 
as monthRevenue
```

A full Working fiddle for that : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f333/6

(Note: I've renamed the `pricefk` column to `priceid` as a standard practice.)

Answer (score 0):

all these query return just one rows  so if you need  al the result on a single row you could try using cross join

```
  select t1.totalrevenue_lifetime, t2.totalrevenue_day, t3.totalrevenue_week , t4.totalrevenue_month
  from (
      SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue_lifetime 
      FROM transaction_table t 
      JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk
  ) t1 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue_day 
    FROM transaction_table t 
    JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  
    where t.transactiondate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

  ) t2 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue_week 
    FROM transaction_table t 
    JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  
    where YEARWEEK(t.transactiondate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())
  ) t3
  CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT  SUM(p.price) as totalrevenue_month 
      FROM transaction_table t 
      JOIN price_tb p ON p.priceid = t.pricefk  
      WHERE MONTH(t.transactiondate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
      AND YEAR(t.transactiondate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
  ) t4
```